# Animation blinks without base href only for google chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, chessboard.js

I followed a simple [tutorial from here](http://chessboardjs.com/examples/5002). Which basically has the following code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://chessboardjs.com/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/chessboard.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="board" style="width: 400px"></div>
    <script src="/js/chess.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/chessboard.js"></script>
    <script>
        var init = function() {
            var board, game = new Chess();
            var makeRandomMove = function() {
                var possibleMoves = game.moves();
                if (game.game_over() === true || game.in_draw() === true || possibleMoves.length === 0) return;
                var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleMoves.length);
                game.move(possibleMoves[randomIndex]);
                board.position(game.fen());
                window.setTimeout(makeRandomMove, 500);
            };
            board = new ChessBoard('board', 'start');
            window.setTimeout(makeRandomMove, 500);
        };
        $(document).ready(init);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything works fine without any problems. But when I removed `<base href="...">` and substituted all links with this base url ( `http://chessboardjs.com/css/chessboard.css` ). I got the same animation but now with a terrible blinking effect.

This blinking effect does not appear in **IE 11.0.1**, **Firefox 25.0.1**, but appears in **Chrome 31.0.1650.57 m**

I do not understand what is the reason (in my opinion nothing should change).

**P.S.** after some time I thought that the reason is due to the Chrome's warning while using jQuery [event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14320), but when I was able to get rid of it, the problem was still there. So I am completely puzzled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am the creator of chessboard.js

This is likely related to [Issue 52](https://github.com/oakmac/chessboardjs/issues/52)

Check that whatever webserver is serving the image files for the chess pieces is setting an appropriate expires header for them; it should be returning an HTTP 304 Not Modified after an image file has already been requested.

What is probably happening is the web server is re-serving the image files on every board update and causing the "flicker" effect.

I might change how this functions in future versions, but for now that should probably do the trick.

Comment: Cool, thank you very much. This was the issue. Also it still strange, because with **base href** it does not reload the images.